# BAT_ник для скачивания

Tags: bat

Как создать батник для скачивания файла с http ссылки и далее его сохранения на диске? Ссылка на сайт имеется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от того, какую "качалку" будете в конечном итоге использовать. Например, в Win10 (1806 вроде) есть `curl` "из коробки". Чтобы им качнуть файл достаточно передать ссылку с параметром `-O`, например:

```
curl -LO http://some.domain.org/downloads/target.zip
```

Если требуется сохранить с альтернативным именем:

```
curl -Lo X:\dest\download.zip http://some.domain.org/downloads/target.zip
```

Более подробно - `curl --help`.
В качестве альтернативных "качалок" можно использовать, например, [wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) или [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/), - документации по ним достаточно.

Comment: Я хочу создать батник и поставить его на "Задачи по расписанию" на сервере.

Comment: @Cool_Dude А версия сервера? Может оказаться так, что в вашем случае лучше использовать PowerShell.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 или Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Cool_Dude, в случае с Win2k8 можно вполне обойтись PowerShell: при создании задачи указываете "Выполнить программу" - powershell.exe, а в качестве аргументов ```/nop /com "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://some.domain.org/downloads/target.zip', 'X:\sklad\target.zip')"```. Для Win2k3 можно либо установить PowerShell (v2 и только), либо использовать WSH сценарии, либо стащить из интернета (установить с помощью ```choco```) wget, curl и т.д. Нюансов очень много - все не пересказать за раз.

Comment: В планировщике заданий, создал задачу. Указал запуск программы: powershell.exe (полный путь через кнопку Обзор), в графе "Добавить аргументы (необязательно)" указал путь к сайту (скопировал ваш указанный аргумент и поменял там ссылку на новую и путь к папке в моем компьютере). Запустил задание, результат 0. Ничего не загрузилось...(((

Comment: @Cool_Dude, проверил под виртуальной машиной, задача отказалась запускаться без полного указания пути PowerShell, - попробуйте в разделе "Выполнить программу" найти PS через "Обзор" (политики PS выставите в RemoteSigned для CurrentUser). Если что, предлагаю перейти в чат, где с вашей стороны ожидаю увидеть последовательность действий создания задачи.

Comment: Я так и сделал. Указал полный путь через Обзор, но тоже ничего не получилось...

Comment: Больше ни у кого вариантов нет, на эту тему?